# ASP .NET Webhook Receiver

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to create a web app that will receive HTTP Posts containing json. All I want to do for now is show that I can receive the requests. I started by creating an ASP .NET web app with Web API template. I added a controller to receive the posts:

```
  public class PostmanController : Controller
{

    [System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
    public void Index([FromBody] string request)
    {

        // Create handler class object
        PostmanHandler test = new PostmanHandler();

        // Pass request to the convertjsontoobject method
        test.ConvertJsonToObject(request);

    }
}
```

As you can see here, I also created a handler in the Models folder:

```
public class PostmanHandler
{
 public void ConvertJsonToObject(string s)
    {
        // Deserialize JSON
        var newData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<testobject>(s);
    }
}
```

Which converts the JSON into a class I made:

```
public class testobject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to test this out to see if it works but I get a 404 response from Postman when I send a POST request. I am sending it to http://localhost:xxxx/api/Postman which I thought follows the routing in the WebApiConfig file that states: routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"

Am I leaving out some sort of routing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're really using Web API (and not MVC), your controller should be a subclass of ApiController (not Controller).

Update: So, you really don't need to handle the deserializing of JSON yourself. Web API will do that for you. Your "request" parameter shouldn't be of type "string", it should actually be of the type that you're trying to deserialize to

```
[HttpPost]
public void PostObject([FromBody]testobject request)
{

    // Your request object should be deserialized already.
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Getting an exception for a null value when deserializing the json now

Answer (score 0):

Take out the API in your URL and try http://localhost:xxxx/Postman. Your controller PostmanController is not a Web API (derived from Controller not ApiController class) so routing template of /api/{controller}/{id} is not correct in this case.

Comment: Thank you. It's now giving me an exception in the handler for "var newData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<testobject>(s);" saying that the value cannot be null. I am including an id and name in the post request from Postman though

Comment: Can you include the raw data with the Form POST? It should be similar to this format: {"request": {"id": "1", "name": "john smith"}} Otherwise, you will get null in your request parameter and will get the error you just described.